# After upgrading to an SSD, lost access to Windows refresh options. How do I get it back?

Tags: windows-8.1, partitioning, ssd

I upgraded my notebook from a spinning disk to an SSD. It's smaller (1TB vs 500GB), but by shrinking the main Windows partition I was able to fit all data, including the recovery partitions.

However, when I shift-click on the reset menu to access boot options, and then select "Advanced" to access the "Refresh" or "Reset" options, they're no longer there, even though all recovery partitions are present.

If I put my old disk back in the machine, the options are back there.

How do I get those options back when running from the SSD?

---

Edit: I managed to find information related to my problem.

The subsystem responsible for the Refresh and Reset options is called the [Windows Recovery Enviroment](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825173.aspx), and it is manipulated by means of the [REAgentC command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825204.aspx).

In my setup, the Recovery Environment lost track of the location of the Windows Recovery Image, possibly due to reordering of the partitions, so `reagentc /info` reported it as disabled.

I managed to fix it by locating the partitions and directories containing the Recovery and OS images, mapping them to drive letters temporarily with `partimage` and pointing to them using the `/setreimage` and `/setosimage` switches of `reagentc`.

The link that originally set me on the right path was this one:

http://kb.stonegroup.co.uk/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=382

Though it was not enough in my case since the location of the RE image was incorrect.

I'm just dumping this info here in case anyone wants to write a properly detailed answer, as I don't have the time right now.

Comment: Yes we know what you are talking about. Refresh is a standard windows 8/8.1 function. For details see here ==> http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2293-refresh-windows-8-a.html

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Come on now, David.  Refresh and Reset are standard terms when it comes to Windows 8.x and greater.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - It is what he is talking about.  The Advanced boot menu only contains a few options and Reset and Restore are two of them.